# Is there a name for this priority queue data structure?

Tags: data-structures, terminology, heaps, priority-queues

While watching a sports tournament, I noticed that the tournament tree looks a lot like a heap. I came up with the following data structure: A complete binary tree where the leaves are elements of some set, and each internal node is the $\max$ of its two children. I came up with a *BuildHeap* algorithm that's $O(n)$, a *GetMax* algorithm that's $O(1)$, an *Insert* algorithm that's $O(\log n)$, and a *Delete* algorithm that's $O(\log n)$. The number of nodes in this "heap" is $2n-1$ where $n$ is the number of elements in the underlying set. The structure is simpler than a binary heap.

Is there a name for this data structure?

[edit]

Code:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

data Heap a = Leaf a | Branch a (Heap a) (Heap a) deriving Show

getMax :: Heap a -> a
getMax (Leaf x) = x
getMax (Branch x _ _) = x

leaf :: Ord a => a -> Heap a
leaf = Leaf

branch :: Ord a => Heap a -> Heap a -> Heap a
branch h1 h2 = Branch (max (getMax h1) (getMax h2)) h1 h2

buildHeap :: Ord a => [a] -> Heap a 
buildHeap xs = fst $ buildSubHeap (length xs) xs
  where buildSubHeap 1 (x:xs) = (Leaf x, xs)
        buildSubHeap n xs = let (leftSubHeap, remainder1) = buildSubHeap (div n 2) xs
                                (rightSubHeap, remainder2) = buildSubHeap (n - div n 2) remainder1
                            in (branch leftSubHeap rightSubHeap, remainder2)

insertIntoHeap :: Ord a => a -> Heap a -> Heap a
insertIntoHeap x (Leaf y) = branch (leaf x) (leaf y)
insertIntoHeap x (Branch m h1 h2) = branch h2 (insertIntoHeap x h1)

deleteInsignificantElement :: Ord a => Heap a -> Heap a
deleteInsignificantElement (Branch _ (Leaf x) (Leaf y)) = Leaf (max x y)
deleteInsignificantElement (Branch _ h1 h2) = branch (deleteInsignificantElement h2) h1

getInsignificantElement :: Ord a => Heap a -> a
getInsignificantElement (Branch _ (Leaf x) (Leaf y)) = min x y
getInsignificantElement (Branch _ h1 h2) = getInsignificantElement h2

replaceMax :: Ord a => Heap a -> a -> Heap a
replaceMax (Leaf x) y = Leaf y
replaceMax (Branch m h1 h2) y | getMax h1 == m = branch (replaceMax h1 y) h2
                              | getMax h2 == m = branch h1 (replaceMax h2 y)
                              | otherwise = undefined

deleteMax :: Ord a => Heap a -> Heap a
deleteMax heap = replaceMax (deleteInsignificantElement heap) (getInsignificantElement heap)

data HeapObserver a = Singleton a | PushHeap a (Heap a) deriving Show

popHeap :: Ord a => Heap a -> HeapObserver a
popHeap (Leaf x) = Singleton x
popHeap heap = PushHeap (getMax heap) (deleteMax heap)

undown :: Down a -> a
undown (Down x) = x

heapsort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
heapsort [] = []
heapsort xs = map undown . flattenHeap . buildHeap . map Down $ xs
  where flattenHeap heap = case popHeap heap of
                           Singleton y -> [y]
                           PushHeap y ys -> y : flattenHeap ys

example_list = [234,234245,13235,14223,12,5,41,24,132,4134,25,234, 94875937, 34059, 784, 34875, 234, 765, 909]

main :: IO ()
main = print (heapsort example_list == reverse (sort example_list))
```

Answer (score 6):

This is essentially a [Segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) which is a data structure that augments an array with a binary tree as you describe such that:

- You have fast set and get at any index
- You have fast "aggregate" queries on ranges
- You can support fast update queries on ranges, for some combinations of updates and queries

The $j$th node at height $k$ in the tree "summarizes" a subarray $[j*2^k, (j+1)*2^k)$ of the original array. Since each element of the array appears in only logarithmically many such subarrays, we can do updates in $O(\log n)$ time.

The range queries can use any associative operation. In your example the operation is $\max$, but other examples include sum, product, even standard deviation (via sum and sum of squares).

---

I originally called this a Fenwick Tree (aka Binary Indexed Tree), which is a similar structure but which compresses the tree into only exactly $n$ storage with no overhead(but loses access to the original array).

Comment: I think you're right and I confuse them all the time

Comment: For clarification: a Segment tree also uses *linear* storage.

Answer (score 1):

You've just reinvented a range-query structure. This is an instance of the more general idea that, if you put all data at only the leaves of a binary tree, you can use internal nodes to represent substructures, and it will work for any kind of structure that can be recursively defined with an $O(1)$ recursive initialization.

In this case, you can see that the structure is just an unordered set with a maximum, which is obviously $O(1)$ recursively definable. It is also clear that you can support Insert and DeleteMax and $O(1)$ GetMax, but not $O(\log n)$ Search. Additionally, if you think a bit you should be able to figure out how to support $O(\log n)$ MergeHeap.